# Quadratic covariation of Martingales

Tags: probability, inequality, stochastic-calculus, martingales

I was succesful at showing that the quadratic covariation $\langle\cdot ,\cdot \rangle_t$ is a positiv semidefinit, symmetric and bilinear form for each $t$ on the set of local martigales. So the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality gives me:
\begin{align*}
|\langle M,N\rangle_t| \leq \sqrt{\langle M,M\rangle_t}\sqrt{\langle N,N\rangle_t}=\sqrt{\langle M\rangle_t}\sqrt{\langle N\rangle_t}
\end{align*}
That is already very nice, but for the proof of Kunita-Watanabe inequality my Professor uses following:

\begin{align*}
|\langle M,N\rangle_t - \langle M,N\rangle_s| \leq \sqrt{\langle M\rangle_t -\langle M\rangle_s}\sqrt{\langle N\rangle_t - \langle N\rangle_s}
\end{align*}
Can someone explain me why this is true? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Fix $s \leq t$. Show that $$\langle M,N \rangle_t^s :=  \langle M,N \rangle_t - \langle M,N \rangle_s $$ defines a symmetric positiv definite bilinear form.

Alternatively: Apply the first inequality (the one you already proved) to the shifted processes $$\tilde{M}_t := M_{t+s}-M_s \qquad \quad \tilde{N}_t := N_{t+s}-M_s, \qquad t \geq 0.$$

Comment: Your hint does the job. But i couldn't show the inequality via your alternative way. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @holic The idea of the alternative way is that $\langle \tilde{M} \rangle_t = \langle M \rangle_{t+s} - \langle M \rangle_s$ for $t \geq 0$.